# How to Generate Message According to Values in Multiple Fields?

Tags: javafx, combobox, textfield

I am building an application using JavaFX. What I am trying to do is generate a message according to the user input values. So there are one text-field and one combo-box and one check-box per row and there are many rows like the following.

[image]

Let's say I will generate three different messages according to the user values. So I need to check whether those fields are empty or not and check each field's value to generate a specific message. Checking fields are okay for just three rows like the above. But I have 10 fields. So I have to check each and generate or append my own message. And also if the user checked the check-box need to group all checked row values. So what I am asking is there any good way (best practice) to achieve what I need or an easy one also? I have tried with `HashMap` and `ArrayList`. But those are not working for this.

Really appreciate it if anybody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably recommend a custom node that you create on your own like below. This example is not supposed to have the same functionality as your application but just to show how to create and use custom nodes. I kept your idea in mind when creating this example it has your textfield combobox and checkbox and they are a little easier to manage. Give it a run and let me know if you have any questions

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Dog", "Cat", "Turkey"));

        ArrayList<HBoxRow> hBoxRowArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
            HBoxRow hBoxRow = new HBoxRow();
            hBoxRow.setComboBoxValues(FXCollections.observableList(itemList));
            hBoxRowArrayList.add(hBoxRow);
            vBox.getChildren().add(hBoxRow.gethBox());
        }

        Button printTextfieldsButton = new Button("Print Textfields");
        printTextfieldsButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            for (HBoxRow hBoxRow : hBoxRowArrayList) {
                System.out.println("hBoxRow.getTextFieldInput() = " + hBoxRow.getTextFieldInput());
            }
        });
        vBox.getChildren().add(printTextfieldsButton);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();
    }

    //Below is the custom Node
    public class HBoxRow {
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

        public HBoxRow(){
            hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            textField.setPrefWidth(150);

            comboBox.setPrefWidth(150);

            checkBox.setOnAction(event -> {
                textField.setDisable(!textField.isDisabled());
                comboBox.setDisable(!comboBox.isDisabled());
            });

            hBox.getChildren().addAll(checkBox, textField, comboBox);
        }

        public void setComboBoxValues(ObservableList observableList) {
            comboBox.setItems(observableList);
        }

        public HBox gethBox(){
            return hBox;
        }

        public String getTextFieldInput(){
            return textField.getText();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I can't vote this because of my low reputation. But I can accept this as the answer. Also can you tell me how to identify each HBoxRow or by values? Because it is giving all results as one. Is there a way to separate them?

Comment: There is plenty of ways to do this as I'm not exactly sure what your program looks like you can create them as local variables if you don't have a lot of them or you could create a field in the HBoxRow called id and you could give each of them an id calling a public setId method or set it in the constructor